# Uniqueness of element

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Group element $a \in G$ have order 6 where $G$ can be any group. Prove that  $a^3, a^4$ are the only elements $b,c$ in the group $G$ such that $a = bc$, $|b| = 2$, $|c| = 3$ and $bc = cb$.

Because $G$ can be any group, I'm really not sure how this could stand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Suppose that $b$ and $c$ are any such elements satisfying those assumptions. Squaring both sides of $a=bc$ yields $a^2=b^2c^2=c^2$. (This is where it is important that $b$ and $c$ commute.)

Use this to solve $c$ in terms of $a$, and that will then give you $b$ in terms of $a$. Mouse over below if you get stuck.

> Since $c$ has order $3$, $a^2=c^2=c^{-1}$, so $c=a^{-2}=a^4$, since $a$ has order $6$. Then $a=ba^4$, so $b=a^{-3}=a^3$. You should also check that $a^3$ and $a^4$ have the claimed properties, but that's almost immediate.

Comment: I just realized that cubing $a=bc$ is ever so slightly easier: $a^3=b^3c^3=b$, so $c=b^{-1}a=a^{-2}=a^4$.

Answer (score 0):

You have $a^3 = b$, $a^4=c$. Then $bc = a^3a^4=a^7=a$, $cb = a^7 = a = bc$.

Moreover, $b^2 = a^6 =e$ and $c^3=a^{12} =e$ (check that $c^2\neq e$).